# $\cos(\frac{\pi x^2}{x^2+x}) = -\cos(\frac{\pi}{x+1})$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How can I find the limit for $x\to \infty$ and $\cos(\frac{\pi*x^2}{x^2+x})$ ?

I know that $$\cos(\frac{\pi x^2}{x^2+x}) = \cos(\frac{π x}{1 + x})$$ But what's the next step?

By using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos(%5Cfrac%7Bpi*x%5E2%7D%7Bx%5E2%2Bx%7D)) I get: $\cos(\frac{\pi x^2}{x^2+x}) = -\cos(\frac{\pi}{x+1})$

It is clear to me that $-\cos(\frac{\pi}{x+1})\to -1$.

But how can I prove $\cos(\frac{\pi x^2}{x^2+x}) = -\cos(\frac{\pi}{x+1})$ ? Or is this step irrelevant to prove $\cos(\frac{\pi x^2}{x^2+x})\to -1$?

Comment: What limit? I mean, for $x\to$?

Comment: I ment $x\to \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's wrong! Try $x=0$.

But for $x\neq 0$ it's true.

Use $\cos(\pi-\alpha)=-\cos\alpha$:

$$\cos\frac{\pi x}{x+1}=-\cos\left(\pi-\frac{\pi x}{x+1}\right)=-\cos\frac{\pi}{x+1}$$

Comment: @Peter It was typo. I fixed. Thank you!